# Looking for a specific combination algorithm to solve a problem

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, algorithm, math

Let’s say I have a purchase total and I have a csv file full of purchases where some of them make up that total and some don’t. Is there a way to search the csv to find the combination or combinations of purchases that make up that total ? Let’s say the purchase total is 155$ and my csv file has the purchases [5.00$,40.00$,7.25$,$100.00,$10.00]. Is there an algorithm that will tell me the combinations of the purchases that make of the total ?

Edit: I am still having trouble with the solution you provided. When I feed this spreadsheet with pandas into the code snippet you provided it only shows one solution equal to 110.04$ when there are three. It is like it is stopping early without finding the final solutions.This is the output that I have from the terminal - [57.25, 15.87, 13.67, 23.25]. The output should be [10.24,37.49,58.21,4.1] and [64.8,45.24] and [57.25,15.87,13.67,23.25]

```
    from collections import namedtuple
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('purchases.csv',parse_dates=["Date"])

from collections import namedtuple
values = df["Purchase"].to_list()
S = 110.04
Candidate = namedtuple('Candidate', ['sum', 'lastIndex', 'path'])
tuples = [Candidate(0, -1, [])]

while len(tuples):
  next = []
  for (sum, i, path) in tuples:
    # you may range from i + 1 if you don't want repetitions of the same purchase
    for j in range(i+1, len(values)):
      v = values[j]
      # you may check for strict equality if no purchase is free (0$)
      if v + sum <= S:
        next.append(Candidate(sum = v + sum, lastIndex = j, path = path + [v]))
        if v + sum == S :
          print(path + [v])

  tuples = next
```

[image: Spreadsheet of Purchases]

Comment: A slight modification of the coin change problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/coin-change-dp-7/ so you only use each coin once would work

Comment: Given the fact that the same result may come from different combinations, I fear you have to test every combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dp solution:

Let `S` be your goal sum

- Build all 1-combinations. Keep those which sums less or equal than S. Whenever one equals S, output it
- Build all 2-combinations reusing the previous ones.
- Repeat

```
from collections import namedtuple
values = [57.25,15.87,13.67,23.25,64.8,45.24,10.24,37.49,58.21,4.1]
S = 110.04
Candidate = namedtuple('Candidate', ['sum', 'lastIndex', 'path'])
tuples = [Candidate(0, -1, [])]

while len(tuples):
  next = []
  for (sum, i, path) in tuples:
    # you may range from i + 1 if you don't want repetitions of the same purchase
    for j in range(i + 1, len(values)):
      v = values[j]
      # you may check for strict equality if no purchase is free (0$)
      if v + sum <= S:
        next.append(Candidate(sum = v + sum, lastIndex = j, path = path + [v]))
        if abs(v + sum - S) <= 1e-2 :
          print(path + [v])
  tuples = next
```

---

More detail about the tuple structure:

What we want to do is to augment a tuple with a new value.

Assume we start with some tuple with only one value, say the tuple associated to `40`.

- its sum is trivially `40`
- the last index added is `1` (it is the number `40` itself)
- the used values is `[40]`, since it is the sole value.

Now to generate the next tuples, we will iterate from the last index (`1`), to the end of the array.

So candidates are `7.25, 100.00, 10.00`

The new tuple associated to `7.25` is:

- sum: `40 + 7.25`
- last index: `2` (`7.25` has index `2` in array)
- used values: values of tuple union `7.25`, so `[40, 7.25]`

The purpose of using the last index, is to avoid considering `[7.25, 40]` and `[40, 7.25]`. Indeed they would be the same combination
So to generate tuples from an old one, only consider values occurring 'after' the old one from the array

At every step, we thus have tuples of the same size, each of them aggregates the values taken, the sum it amounts to, and the next values to consider to augment it to a bigger size

edit: to handle floats, you may replace (v+sum)<=S by abs(v+sum - S)<=1e-2 to say a solution is reach when you are *very close* (here distance arbitrarily set to 0.01) to solution

edit2: same code here as in https://repl.it/repls/DrearyWindingHypertalk (which does give

```
[64.8, 45.24]
[57.25, 15.87, 13.67, 23.25]
[10.24, 37.49, 58.21, 4.1]
```

Comment: Would you be able to explain the tuple part a bit more in depth :)?

Comment: @MRS_ROBOT updated more detail about the tuple, do not hesitate to tell me if I am still unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have one more question. In the solution you provided are items in values only being used once ? The items in the values list can only be used once in S unless the item shows up twice in values.For instance if values=[1,2,3] and S = 3 the output would be [3],[1, 2],[1, 1, 1] when the output should only be [3],[1,2]. Maybe I explained my problem poorly sorry.

Comment: It is written in comment. If you want repetition iterate from lastIndex included (so range(i, len(values)), if you do not want repetition iterate from lastIndex excluded (so range(i+1, len(values)) @MRS_ROBOT

Comment: Thank you so much! I’m trying to help my Dad out with a problem at work and this is a great start.

Comment: Tip.  If you `import collections` then you can use `collections.namedtuple` to create a tuple and name its fields for clarity.

Comment: I did not know namedtuple,  slick. Thx @btilly

Comment: @grodzi I just tried to stress test the code snippet you provided and I cant seem to get it to work and I'm not sure what's going wrong. I edited my question to show what is going on :)

Comment: your initial problem was with integers here you added some floats so the sum of floats does not really equal S but is very close to. doing a abs(v + sum - S) <= 1e-2 does the trick see update (plz avoid doing back&forth and eventually open a new post for new problem you encounter! (here it makes sense though))

Comment: Now it is not outputting anything. Could you take one more look at it?

Comment: sorry @MRS_ROBOT I wrongly replaced the wrong if ... please find the updated code and the repl.it. Hopefully this is the final codedown